# How to save ModelForm fields that are disabled in a template? (Not included in POST request)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a ModelForm and an UpdateView to update the model's values.

To simplify, let's say I have formfields A,B and C. My template displays A,B and C, but users can only edit A and B. C is calculated based on the values of A and B (server-side only).

I am calculating C in the clean_C method of the modelform. If I set C to 'disabled' in my template, the value is not updated in my model. (I'm guessing this is because it is not included in the POST data?) If I set C to readonly, it saves correctly.

1. Is there a way to still save C while keeping the field disabled?

(to clarify, there is nothing in my model/modelform that disables the field, this is only in the template)

It looks like the clean_C method runs regardless of the disabled/readonly flag in the template, and the appropriate value is included in the cleaned_data dictionary in the modelform's clean method.

2. I've been digging through the Django source code to figure out why this happens. Can someone point me to where the data from cleaned_data is saved to the ModelForm / Model?

Comment: Doesn't question 2 answer itself? That is done when you call `form.save()`. But you should ask yourself whether you need to include this data in the form, and send it to the template, at all. If you're calculating it in the view, why can't you do that on submission and assign it to the resulting model instance at that point?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well `form.save()` looks like it boils down to `self.instance.save()`, so at that point the data from cleaned_data should have already been applied to the model instance, which is what I'm trying to find. I guess I could make the same changes in the view instead of the modelform

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. Well the actual assignment happens in [`construct_instance`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L31) which is called from [`_post_clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L399) which in turn is called from the base [`Form.full_clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L363) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks like a no. This ignores fields that are not included in post data: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1e429df748867097451bf0b45d1080ae6828d921/django/forms/models.py#L49
2. Form.full_clean -> _post_clean -> construct https://github.com/django/django/blob/1e429df748867097451bf0b45d1080ae6828d921/django/forms/models.py#L31

Thanks @DanielRoseman!